# Wildcard in CSS Value

Tags: css, wildcard

Hi I'm just wondering if something like the below can be done in CSS.

-----------edited------------

```
#divlink .link1 a {background:url(bluepic_bg.jpg)}
#divlink .link2 a {background:url(orangepic_bg.jpg)}
#divlink .link3 a {background:url(purplepic_bg.jpg)}
```

- hover call

  ## divlink a:hover {background:url(*-2.jpg)}

what i want the "hover call" to achieve is:

```
#divlink .link1 a {background:url(bluepic_bg-2.jpg)}
#divlink .link2 a {background:url(orangepic_bg-2.jpg)}
#divlink .link3 a {background:url(purplepic_bg-2.jpg)}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: What would it mean? Get all `.jpg` images from currect directory it put them into background? No, that's not possible.

Comment: no, you can't include files like that.

Comment: You want to put ALL images in ALL anchor tags? You can't but you can use SASS to automate that.

Comment: My apologies for a confusing question, kindly find the edited question above. thanks

Comment: Better to combine the default and hover graphics (or the graphics for all the elements) into a css sprite and then just change the background position.

Comment: oh yeah @steveax that will work! brilliant! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @steveax suggestion, I have come to realize the below solution..

- create an extended background image and re-position on hover

  > divlink .link1 a {width:28px; background:url(bluepic_bg.jpg)}
  >
  > divlink .link2 a {width:28px; url(orangepic_bg.jpg)}
  >
  > divlink .link3 a {width:28px; url(purplepic_bg.jpg)}
  >
  > divlink div[id^="link"] a:hover {background-position: -28px 0}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying cannot be achieved using traditional CSS, the thing you are trying can be done in selectors

```
div[id^="edit"]
```

will select all the `div` elements whose ids start with the word `edit` or you can use

```
div[id*="edit"]
```

will find the word `edit` anywhere in the `id` and why someone would even use a star? that will be vague, how will the CSS decide that you want to attach what background?

Comment: My apologies for a confusing question, kindly find the edited question above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This matter is almost unlikely to happen. It's not sensible to put all image backgrounds for just one element. It cannot happen.

Comment: My apologies for a confusing question, kindly find the edited question above. thanks